# How can we solve parameter greater than these problems in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT IF(@maxins < @num_of_ins, @maxins, @num_of_ins) 
FROM( SELECT @maxins :=4, @num_of_ins:=10) f1

Ans: 4 [True]
But 10 [False]
```

Comment: Adn what is your question?

Comment: You try something like `IF (NULL < NULL)` so mysql return `false`.In the meantime `@num_of_ins` has been valued and is 10

Comment: *"You try something like IF (NULL < NULL) so mysql return false"* @AlbertoMoro `NULL` is "unknown" in the SQL standard.. `NULL < NULL` should return into `NULL` as well in all RDMS..

Answer (score 2):

This happen  the first time  .. so try assign the var value before the select

```
set  @maxins =4;
set  @num_of_ins=10;

SELECT IF(@maxins < @num_of_ins, @maxins, @num_of_ins)
```

Comment: What about `SELECT IF(@maxins < @num_of_ins, @maxins, @num_of_ins) .... CROSS JOIN(SELECT @maxins := 4, @num_of_ins := 10) AS init_user_params` to do the init in one query..